# Python Crash Course 9-8

Tags: python-3.x

I'm going through the book Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes, and I'm stuck on the 8th 'Try It yourself' on chapter 9

```
class Priviledges():
    def __init__(self, priviledges):
        self.priviledges2 = ['can add post', 'can delete post',
                             'can ban user', 'can unban user']

    def show_priviledges(self):
        for priviledge in self.priviledges:
            print(priviledge)

class User():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, age):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.username = username
        self.age = age

    def describe_user(self):
        print(self.first_name.title())
        print(self.last_name.title())
        print(self.username)
        print(self.age)

    def greet_user(self):
        print('Hello, ' + self.first_name.title() + ', how are you doing?')

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, age):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, username, age)
        self.priviledges = Priviledges()

admin = Admin('1','1','1','1')
admin.priviledges.show_priviledges()
```

So far, I type this in, however every time I run it I get the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/DedProtectr/Desktop/Chapter 9 Labs/Lab 9-8.py", line 35, in <module>
admin = Admin('1','1','1','1')
File "C:/Users/DedProtectr/Desktop/Chapter 9 Labs/Lab 9-8.py", line 33, in __init__
self.priviledges = Priviledges()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'priviledges'
```

Can someone help me out here? What did I type wrong?

Comment: Instantiating the `Priviledges` class takes one argument, as shown in the definition. The relevant call (in `Admin.__init__`) uses no argument.

Comment: Pedantry: the spelling is privileges. No 'd'.

Comment: Actually, since the `priviledges` argument in `Priviledges.__init__` is never used, consider removing it from `__init__` there.

Answer (score 1):

You left a typo in class Priviledges(), self.priviledges2 should be self.priviledges.

```
class Priviledges():
def __init__(self):
    self.priviledges2 = ['can add post', 'can delete post',
                         'can ban user', 'can unban user']
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Class, the `__init__()` function is run as soon as an object is called as that class. This means that any arguments that are needed in the `__init__` function need to be passed when you call that class. In your 'Privileges' class definition, you `__init__` takes one argument other than `self`, `privileges`. However, in your `Admin` class definition, you are calling `privileges` without any arguments at all. However, since it looks like you aren't even using the argument in the `privileges` class, consider removing it.

```
class Priviledges():
    def __init__(self):
        self.priviledges2 = ['can add post', 'can delete post',
                             'can ban user', 'can unban user']

    def show_priviledges(self):
        for priviledge in self.priviledges:
            print(priviledge)

class User():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, age):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.username = username
        self.age = age

    def describe_user(self):
        print(self.first_name.title())
        print(self.last_name.title())
        print(self.username)
        print(self.age)

    def greet_user(self):
        print('Hello, ' + self.first_name.title() + ', how are you doing?')

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, age):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, username, age)
        self.priviledges = Priviledges()

admin = Admin('1','1','1','1')
admin.priviledges.show_priviledges()
```